# Shell Script: Not able to traverse files using $HOME or ~ in the path

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script which performs some operation on files.
This script will run on various servers so I want to keep the path of these files from home directory.

```
DAT_FILE_PATH='$HOME/projs/build/dat'
```

I'm using ksh as shell.
The above path indeed exists. If I run cd in console

```
cd $HOME/projs/build/dat
```

This works. But in script if I do ls $HOME/projs/build/dat'. It says  **No such file or directory.**

Similarly, If I use `sed` on `$HOME/projs/build/dat/abc.dat`, result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double quotes

```
DAT_FILE_PATH="$HOME/projs/build/dat"
```

"The difference between single and double quotes becomes more important when you’re dealing with variables on the command line"
[Go here for more details](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/)